# Regex to get all text occurrences between parentheses encapsulated by a second pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will get all the text occurences between parentheses, having in mind that all the content is encapsulated by the word BEGIN and the chars ---- at the end.

Input example:

```
BEGIN       ) Tj\nET37.66 533 Td\n( Td\n(I NEED THIS TEXT      ) Tj\nET\nBT\n37.334 Td\n(AND ALSO NEED THIS TEXT         ) Tj\nET\nBT\n37.55 Td\n(------------
```

Expected matches:

```
I NEED THIS TEXT
AND ALSO NEED THIS TEXT
```

I already did something like `(?<=BEGIN).*(?=\(--)` to the outside pattern, but i couldn't figure out how to get all text occurrences inside parentheses between this.

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/mCE8hm/1

Comment: What about the parenthesis inside `Td\n( Td\n`?

Comment: Please mention tool/lang you're using.

Comment: @bobblebubble it is a python code extracting info from a pdf file content.

Comment: So, the pattern above will only work with PyPi `regex` module, not `re`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python PyPi regex library, you can use

```
(?s)(?:\G(?!^)\)|BEGIN)(?:(?!\(--).)*?\((?!--)\K[^()]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ul6FWj/2)

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL inline modifier making `.` match line break chars
- `(?:\G(?!^)\)|BEGIN)` - either `BEGIN` or the end of the previous successful match and a `)` right after
- `(?:(?!\(--).)*?` - any char, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a `(--` char sequence
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?!--)` - right after `(`, there should be no `--`
- `\K` - match reset operator: what was matched before is discarded from the overall match memory buffer
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`

Comment: I just get one problem, this text that i provided is located inside another bigger text, and this solution is getting all the patterns between parentheses. I need the pattern to stop find matches when the sequence of - chars appears. Can i solve this somehow?

Comment: @PatrickFreitas `(?:(?!\(--).)*?` does that check (otherwise, I would have just used `.*?`). Please share a regex demo showcasing the issue.

Comment: here it is https://regex101.com/r/ul6FWj/1

Comment: @PatrickFreitas Ok, the `(` that is right before the match should not be followed with `--`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\(((?:(?!BEGIN).)*?)\)(?=.*---)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vDWVTd/1)

---

- `\(((?:(?!BEGIN).)*?)\)` - Match everything between `( )`, but not `BEGIN`

  - `(?=.*---)` - `.*---` must follow after this match